# NSBlockOperation EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c++

I created a class that implements a few methods. These methods are called by another class and are managed through a NSBlockOperation.

My NSBlockOperation working properly, I have problems when I try to evaluate a variable:

**EXC_BAD_ACCESS**

I have done much research on the internet and [this](http://blog.pioneeringsoftware.co.uk/2012/03/06/out-parameters-when-arcing) is the one closest to my problem. I tried to do as sugerito but you encounter the same problem.

Do you have any suggestions?

EDIT:

This is Stack trace:

```
2015-05-09 15:24:45.976 OutParameters[12326:743087] Stack trace : (
    0   OutParameters                       0x000000010e5d6602 -[ListOperation _method1:] + 194
    1   OutParameters                       0x000000010e5d646f __25-[ListOperation method1:]_block_invoke + 95
    2   Foundation                          0x000000010e74257f __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010e6830b2 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 98
    4   Foundation                          0x000000010e665774 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 645
    5   Foundation                          0x000000010e665383 __NSOQSchedule_f + 184
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001113f4614 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001113db6a7 _dispatch_queue_drain + 2176
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001113dacc0 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 235
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001113de3b9 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1359
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001113dfb17 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 111
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000111761637 _pthread_wqthread + 729
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011175f40d start_wqthread + 13
)
```

---

The modified code:

```
- (IBAction)testCallMethod:(id)sender {
    NSString * output;
    [self.listOperationObj method1:&output];
    NSLog(@"Output: %@", output);
}
```

And

```
@interface ListOperation : NSObject

-(void)method1:(NSString**)output;

@end

#define MAX_OPERATIONS 10
//define a log-level
static int logLevel = CSLOG_LEVEL_INFO;
@interface ListOperation ()
// Tail used to synchronize the methods
@property NSOperationQueue *queue;
@end

#pragma mark - Public methods

@implementation ListOperation

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        _queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
        if(_queue) {
            [_queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
        }else {
            NSLog(@"TokenMgr creation failed: error creating operation queue");
            self = nil;
        }
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)method1:(NSString *__autoreleasing *)output{
    LOGFSTART
    if([self _isQueueFull] == FALSE) {
        WEAK
        NSBlockOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
            STRONG
            [strongSelf _method1:output];
        }];
        [self.queue addOperation:operation];
        [operation waitUntilFinished];
    }
    else {
        LOGE(@"TokenMgr's queue is full, aborting operation");
    }
    LOGFEND
}

#pragma mark - private methods

-(void)_method1:(NSString *__autoreleasing *)output{
    std::string testString = "try put string";
    *output = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:testString.c_str()];
}

- (BOOL) _isQueueFull {
    return self.queue.operationCount > MAX_OPERATIONS;
}

@end
```

With this change gives me the same error if I press the button repeatedly.

Comment: Post the stack trace from when it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem has nothing to do with the blocks. You have a code snippet that says:

```
- (IBAction)testCallMethod:(id)sender {
    NSString *__autoreleasing * output;
    [self.listOperationObj method1:output];
    NSLog(@"Output: %@", *output);
}
```

That won't work because `output` will not point to a valid memory address, and when you try to dereference that uninitialized pointer with `*output = ...`, it will crash.

Instead,
that should be:

```
- (IBAction)testCallMethod:(id)sender {
    NSString *output;
    [self.listOperationObj method1:&output];
    NSLog(@"Output: %@", output);
}
```

Now `output` references a real `NSString *` pointer which you can populate with a reference to an object.

---

There is a second, deeper issue, namely the use of `* __autoreleasing *` references for an object instantiated inside the operation. Operations have their own autorelease pool, so you have a race condition with the object being released with your use of it back in `testCallMethod`.

Instead, one generally uses completion blocks to pass data back to the caller. Thus:

```
- (IBAction)testCallMethod:(id)sender {
    [self.listOperationObj method2:^(NSString *output) {
        NSLog(@"Output: %@", output);
    }];
}
```

and

```
- (void)method2:(void (^)(NSString *))completionHandler {
    LOGFSTART
    if([self _isQueueFull] == FALSE) {
        WEAK
        NSBlockOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
            STRONG
            [strongSelf _method2:completionHandler];
        }];
        [self.queue addOperation:operation];
        // [operation waitUntilFinished];  // not needed any more
    }
    else {
        LOGE(@"TokenMgr's queue is full, aborting operation");
    }
    LOGFEND
}

-(void)_method2:(void (^)(NSString *))completionHandler {
    std::string testString = "try put string";
    NSString *output = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:testString.c_str()];
    completionHandler(output);
}
```

Note, by the way, this also solves another problem with your example, the fact that you had to put a `waitUntilFinished` call in there. You never should call `waitUntilFinished` from the main thread. If you use completion blocks, like above, that's no longer needed.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried to do as I advised her. It seems to work only sometimes. If I press the button quickly gives me the same error, sometimes even the first time we press.

Comment: Yep, that's a second, completely unrelated problem. Notice that it's crashing when you try to use `output` back in the view controller, not the use of it within `_method1`. See revised answer for discussion of this other problem and the common solution for how to pass data back safely.

Comment: "That won't work because `output` will be NULL" Actually, it should be uninitialized. This is a plain C pointer type, not an ARC managed type.

Comment: @newacct - Agreed. The observation is that it doesn't point to a valid `NSString *`, and thus attempts to dereference it will fail. But I've clarified my answer. Thanks.